# Jest doesn't work in a NestJS/TypeScript/ESModules app

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs, es6-modules

I am trying to enable Jest to work in my NestJS application, which I have configured to work in an ESModules package. However, when I run the tests, I get an error:

```
    <path>/server/src/common/http-exception/http-exception.filter.spec.ts:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { HttpExceptionFilter } from './http-exception.filter.js';                                                                                   
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1495:14)
```

**How to get it to work?** I want to continue using ESModules since it works fine in the non-test files.

---

Here's my setup (briefly):

- *package.json*

  ```json
  {
    "name": "server",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "jest"
    }
  }
  ```
- *tsconfig.json* (some of the shown options are derived from a parent tsconfig; an effective result is shown below)

  ```json
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "noEmit": true, // this is set to 'false' in tsconfig.build.json
      "target": "es2020",
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
      "sourceMap": true,

      "strict": true,
      "allowImportingTsExtensions": false, // this seems to be important; see the note below 
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true
    }
  }
  ```

  - A note about `allowImportingTsExtensions`. The project is a monorepo, and what's shown in this question is its `server` part/package. There's also a `client` package. In the `client/tsconfig.json`, the `allowImportingTsExtensions` option is set to `true`. And it works fine: if a component is defined in `component.tsx`, then the test can `import { Component } from './component.tsx'` just fine (note: using `.tsx` extension). Moreover, if I change `import … from '….tsx'` to `import … from '….js'` (which should be allowed), it doesn't work anymore ("the file `component.js` is not found"). I am perfectly fine with importing `.tsx` but this behavior requires `"moduleResolution": "bundler"` and `"noEmit": true`, which isn't compatible with how NestJS works (it seems to work with `dist/**/*.js` files; if there are no files in `dist`, it'll fail). Therefore, I set `allowImportingTsExtensions` to `false` and use `.js` extensions in test files. But (I think) if I could set `allowImportingTsExtensions` to `true` somehow, and use `.ts` extensions in imports in test files, **this might fix the whole thing**. So far, I'm not sure how to do it, and whether this is possible at all with NestJS (and whether it would be the fix).
- *jest.config.ts*

  ```
  export default {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    rootDir: '.',
    projects: [
      {
        displayName: 'unit',
        testMatch: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.spec.ts'],
      },
    ],
  }
  ```
- *src/common/http-exception/http-exception.filter.ts*

  ```
  import { BaseExceptionFilter } from '@nestjs/core'

  @Catch()
  export class HttpExceptionFilter extends BaseExceptionFilter {
    // implementation
  }
  ```
- *src/common/http-exception/http-exception.filter.spec.ts*

  ```
  import { HttpExceptionFilter } from './http-exception.filter.js'

  describe('HttpExceptionFilter', () => {
    // tests
  })
  ```

Comment: Went with `vitest` instead of `jest`. No regrets so far.